Visual Studio hangs when debug project with boost
I use Visual Studio 2022 community for development app on ubuntu 22.04. I use gcc 11.4 and cmake.
I create simple project with boost and use multi-index containers. Boost installed from repositories. When I try to debug code that uses the Boost step by step a window with an error appears

Undefined command: "d_index_node<boost". Try "help"

and then Visual Studio hangs. If I start debugging and don't set breakpoint or debug step by step through the error window does not appear. If I debug code that doesn't use Boost, the error window does not appear.
Window with error.
I have no idea why it happens.
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/hashed_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/sequenced_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/random_access_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/identity.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>

using namespace boost::lambda;
using namespace ::boost;
using namespace ::boost::multi_index;
using namespace std;

//from boost doc 
struct employee
{
    int         id;
    std::string name;
    int         ssnumber;

    employee(int id, const std::string& name, int ssnumber) :
        id(id), name(name), ssnumber(ssnumber) {}

    bool operator<(const employee& e)const { return id < e.id; }
};

typedef multi_index_container<
    employee,
    indexed_by<
    // sort by employee::operator<
    ordered_unique<boost::multi_index::identity<employee> >,

    // sort by less<string> on name
    ordered_non_unique
    <boost::multi_index::tag<struct employeeByIdNonUniq>,
    member<employee, std::string, &employee::name> >,

    // sort by less<int> on ssnumber
    ordered_unique
    <boost::multi_index::tag<struct employeeByIdUniq>,
    member<employee, int, &employee::ssnumber> >
    >
> employee_set;

struct comp_id
{
    // compare an ID and an employee
    bool operator()(int x, const employee& e2)const { return x <                             
    e2.id; }

    // compare an employee and an ID
    bool operator()(const employee& e1, int x)const { return 
    e1.id < x; }
};

int main()
{

    employee_set es;

    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
        employee emp(i, "Name" + to_string(i), 3105 + i);
        es.insert(emp);
    }

    auto& hashedOrderIndex = es.get<employeeByIdUniq>();

    //if build with this line debugging does not work
    auto oneElementIterator = hashedOrderIndex.find(24);

    employee_set::iterator p0 = es.lower_bound(5, comp_id());
    employee_set::iterator p1 = es.upper_bound(10, comp_id());

    while (p0 != p1) {
        string name = (*p0).name;
        std::cout << to_string((*p0).id) << " " << name <<   
        std::endl;
        p0++;
    }   
    return 0;
}

i found what if build project with this line debugging doenst work.

auto oneElementIterator = hashedOrderIndex.find(24);

cmake file
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project ("boost_multiindex_test")

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/home/user123/boost_1.86_build/" )

FIND_PACKAGE( Boost 1.86 COMPONENTS program_options REQUIRED )

message ( "Status ${Boost_LIBRARIES}, include dir         
${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}, boost root ${BOOST_ROOT}" )

set(SOURCE_FILES 
    "boost_example.cpp"
    )

include_directories (
        ./
        ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    )

add_executable (boost_example ${SOURCE_FILES} )


This seems to be related to debug visualizers. Perhaps they can be disabled/updated to match your boost version.

I was unable to repro the issue,from the command line output it seems that your installation is corrupted.Tested on a simple project with VS 17.11.0 and Boost_1_86_0(installed with zipfile) and the debugging was running smoothly.Would you mind trying to upgrade the library as well as VS IDE?

i have updated VS and downloaded boost 1.86. That  error still appears.  I tried use boost as header files  "include_directories (boost_1_86_0)" and use boost as package "FIND_PACKAGE( Boost 1.86 COMPONENTS program_options REQUIRED ) ", error appears

Did you add the boost library path to both Include Directory and Library Directory in project properties-VC++ Directories?

I dont  add the boost library path in project properties. I will try, but doesn't the  VS take paths from cmake file?

if Boost library environment variable not set cmake won't be able to find them.So did the VS.Please share more detail about your project code if the error still appear as I was unable to repro from the very beginning.

i will add example code
